# How to get certain data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

How do I classify the data in JSON returned by the API with javascript.

The data given by the API:

```
{  
   "referenceNumber":"55f97f3be4b0503165e858c5",
   "phoneNumber":"7877599999",
   "amount":15.00,
   "transStatus":"COMPLETED",
   "responseStatus":{  
      "status":"SUCCESS",
      "statusDescription":"The request is successful."
   }
}
```

I want to receive the number from `phoneNumber` with javascript.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but assuming the the JSON obj is stored in a variable `response`, just do `response.phoneNumber`

Comment: the JSON is given by the api, what i want to do is classify all that data so i can only get the phoneNumber

Comment: I don't know what classify means in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse(apiResponse);

var phoneNumber = data.phoneNumber;
```

Comment: document.getElementById("myPhone2").innerHTML = (this.phoneNumber); thats what the api sends with the referenceNumber and all the other things but i dont know how to clasify it to only display phoneNumber because it is not a varibale

Comment: @Bryan take the `data` variable in the api response and do before the lines stated above: `this.phoneNumber=data.phoneNumber;`